# Combining MahApps.Metro and Caliburn.Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, mahapps.metro

Well im trying to use MahApps.Metro and Caliburn.Micro together but im getting some problems

Here is my bootstrapper

```
public sealed class TestBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<ShellViewModel> 
{
    private CompositionContainer container;

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog(AssemblySource.Instance.Select(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()));

        CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();

        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new AppWindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue(container);

        container.Compose(batch);
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
        var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

        if (exports.Count() > 0)
        {
            return exports.First();
        }

        return base.GetInstance(serviceType, key);
    }
}
```

And here is my AppWindowManager

```
public sealed class AppWindowManager : WindowManager
{
    static readonly ResourceDictionary[] resources;
    static AppWindowManager()
    {
        resources = new ResourceDictionary[] 
        {
            new ResourceDictionary
            { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) },
            new ResourceDictionary
            { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) },
            new ResourceDictionary
            { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) },
            new ResourceDictionary
            { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) },
            new ResourceDictionary
            { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) },
            new ResourceDictionary
            { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute) }
        };
    }

    protected override Window EnsureWindow(object model, object view, bool isDialog)
    {
        MetroWindow window = view as MetroWindow;
        if (window == null)
        {
            window = new MetroWindow()
            {
                Content = view,
                SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
            };
            window.MinHeight = 150;
            window.MinWidth = 500;
            foreach (ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary in resources)
            {
                window.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
            }
            window.SetValue(View.IsGeneratedProperty, true);
            Window owner = this.InferOwnerOf(window);
            if (owner != null)
            {
                window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
                window.Owner = owner;
            }
            else
            {
                window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Window owner2 = this.InferOwnerOf(window);
            if (owner2 != null && isDialog)
            {
                window.Owner = owner2;
            }
        }
        return window;
    }
}
```

This works somewhat but i get a black border around my window until i resize see image below
[image]

Why is there a black border and how can i get rid of it (If i manually resize the window the border goes away.)?

Comment: Thanks for posting this, your code above saved me quite a bit of time!

Comment: https://github.com/ziyasal/Caliburn.Metro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Caliburn.Micro 2 and Mahapps.Metro 1 the above is no longer a valid combination of the two frameworks.

After some digging through Caliburn.Micro documentations and following out dated guides I came up with the following.

First create the bootstrapper like so:

```
public class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    private CompositionContainer container;

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void Configure() 
    {
        container = new CompositionContainer(
            new AggregateCatalog(
                AssemblySource.Instance.Select(
                x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()
                )
            );

        CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();

        batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());
        batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());
        batch.AddExportedValue(container);

        container.Compose(batch);

    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key) 
    {
        string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(service) : key;
        var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

        if(exports.Any())
        {
            return exports.First();
        }

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return container.GetExportedValues<object>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(service));
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance) 
    {
        container.SatisfyImportsOnce(instance);
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) 
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
    }
}
```

Next add the bootstrapper to the App.xaml file along with the MahApps.Metro resources like so:

```
<Application x:Class="your-namespace.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:your-namespace">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The next step is to ensure your ShellViewModel has the proper exports (this is simple requirements for setting up mef bootstrapper, and **don't forget to create the IShell class (not going to show that here as it is standard)**) like so:

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ShellViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell 
{

}
```

Last but not least we need to setup the ShellView to use the MahApps.Metro Window:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="your-namespace.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro">

    <Grid Background="White">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello Caliburn Micro!"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   FontSize="20" />
    </Grid>

</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

Hope this helps anyone else looking to combine Caliburn.Micro and MahApps.Metro in their latest iterations.

Comment: If some one could verify that this is the correct solution then i will mark it as answer!

Comment: Phil, thankyou for posting this, this worked for me using the latest versions of Caliburn and Mahapps Metro.

Comment: Your post doesn't seem to give any indication as to how new windows are created as MetroWindow's. Caliburn's default WindowManager always creates Windows, not MetroWindows. Do you  have a solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the SizeToContent was the problem!

Comment: Perhaps you should mark it as the answer then, maybe add some more info if relevant?

Comment: For those interested, it seems that just removing the "SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight" fixes the problem

Answer (score 3):

Solution for that problem is setting ResizeMode property to "NoResize" then border is rendered properly.

```
window = new MetroWindow()
{
    Content = view,
    SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
};
```